# C#: Perform PictureBox.Click if pressed enter

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Here is my code.

```
   protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            loginButton.Click; //PictureBox & It doesn't work.
            return true; 
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

How to fix this? Been searching around but I couldn't find a correct one. Thanks in advance.

Here is how my form looks.
[image: CGC Gadets Co.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loginButton_Click(new object(), new EventArgs());
```

try this one to replace to your loginButton.Click

Comment: @CarlHolmgren its ok bro, Welcome !

Comment: Don't pass `new object()` in the `sender` parameter, just pass `this` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`loginButton.Click` is the event handler. You should call `loginButton.PerformClick();`

Comment: Tried that and I am getting this error. http://puu.sh/kviQv/f1f52713f7.png Here is the preview of my form for you to be clarified why. http://puu.sh/kviFr/687c3059d3.png

Comment: Naming `PictureBox` as `loginButton` is a clever idea.

Comment: Call event handler directly then: `if (loginButton.Click != null) loginButton.Click(loginButton, EventArgs.Empty);`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AcceptButton` property of your form to be the button you want clicked when enter is pressed. This will also have the effect of providing the outline around the button that indicates to the user that if they press enter, it will be the same as clicking that button.

[image: Property view]

You can also set this through code in your constructor (or elsewhere if need be) by doing

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AcceptButton = loginButton;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a PictureBox not a button. http://puu.sh/kviFr/687c3059d3.png

Here is the error I am getting using the code you gave. http://puu.sh/kviIn/a6cfe7c190.png

Comment: In that case the two best options I see are: use a button instead and set the `Image` property of it to your image, or have your pictureBox_Click method just call some other method like OnLoginClicked, and then call OnLoginClicked in your keypress handler.

Comment: Mind if I ask a sample on how to do it? Thanks for your efforts by the way.